# 'nilClass' with geocoder on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to implement `geocoder` in my rails 4 app, but I'm having problems with initialization. The app properly creates, deletes, edits, etc., but when I try to implement the `nearbys` method in the `show` template I get a `NoMethodError in Events#show` with `` undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass ``. The app performs everything perfectly when I run it on rails 3 with `attr_accessible`, but right when I switch to rails 4 and change to strong parameters I get this error. I know it's something super simple, I just can't see what I'm missing.

Here's my `event` model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
end
```

Here's my `events_controller`:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @events = Event.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance)
    else
      @events = Event.all
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, address: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, address: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :event_date, :start_time, :end_time, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :description, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Here's my `show` template:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @event.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Event date:</b>
  <%= @event.try(:event_date).strftime("%a, %B %d") %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Start time:</b>
  <%= @event.try(:start_time).strftime("%l:%M%p") %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>End time:</b>
  <%= @event.try(:end_time).strftime("%l:%M%p") %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Address:</b>
  <%= @event.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Latitude:</b>
  <%= @event.latitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Longitude:</b>
  <%= @event.longitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @event.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Organizer:</b>
  <%= @event.user.name %>
</p>

<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@event.latitude}%2C#{@event.longitude}" %>

<h3>Nearby events</h3>
<ul>
  <% for event in @event.nearbys(10) %>
      <li><%= link_to event.address, event %> (<%= event.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

I get the error on line 52 of the `show` template (`for event in @event.nearbys(10)`).
I appreciate any help at all!

Comment: where's the code for `nearbys` ?

Comment: I think `nearbys` should be from the `geocode` gem.

Comment: ah ok, i thought you implemented it

Comment: did you check if event is nil? if not does nearbys return nil?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady Thank you. Your question led me to this:

`SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]`
`=> #<Event id: 1, name: "Tea Party", event_date: "2015-03-26", start_time: "2000-01-01 14:30:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 14:30:00", address: "Boston, MA", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, description: "This is a tea party.", user_id: 2, created_at: "2015-03-26 14:30:07", updated_at: "2015-03-26 14:36:48">`

There I noticed the nil fields for `latitude` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my `seeds.rb` file. The `create` action correctly geocodes the `:latitude` and `:longitude` fields, but I didn't enter values for those fields when first seeding the database.